# How to persist internal state conditionally in React on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose a component needs to check the current state and conditionally allow the component to update or not when a new props is passed in.

What are possible ways to store the internal state of the component when a props is passed inside.

Comment: Please put comments with downvotes. Share the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

In React component, an update can be caused by changes to `props` or `state`. This changes to props can be passed down from top hierarchy or can be passed from changes in `Redux state` (which is mapped to a component using `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` ).

Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in `state` or `props`.

`shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new `props` or `state` are being received. Defaults to `true`.

Suppose at some point the current `state` of the application is as follows:

```
this.state = {
     firstName: 'John Doe',
     updateError: '',
     canEdit: 1
}
```

For example: we need to make sure that if the component needs to update then current `state` should be empty as its initial `state` as shown:

```
this.state = {
     firstName: '',
     updateError: '',
     canEdit: null
}
```

Then the `shouldComponentUpdate()` can be used as shown:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  let _this = this;
  let isStateEmpty = Object.keys(this.state).some(function(k) {
    let _item = _this.state[k];
    if (_item) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return isStateEmpty;
}
```

If `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns `false`, then `componentWillUpdate()`, `render()`, and `componentDidUpdate()` will not be invoked. 
`shouldComponentUpdate()` can be used also when Redux is used to change external `state` of the application (use `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` ).

`shouldComponentUpdate()` can be used effectively with `componentWillUpdate()` to perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

Hope this helped. Thanks